# jQuery change format not changing format to stated format

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

My Code:

```
/* DATE PICKER */
$('#thedate').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
/* FLOW DIFFERENTIATION */

//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#thedate').datepicker();

  $('#checkDate').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedDate = $('#thedate').datepicker('getDate');

    console.log(selectedDate);
```

What is odd is that I have defined my date format as dd-mm-year and yet the output is:

```
Wed May 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

But it has to be DAY

```
Feb 05 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

EDIT: Removed the 2nd datepick() so it won't return to default. Yet I still get May 02.

If I add:

```
$( '#thedate' ).datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
```

It logs 05/02/2018, however I need it to log like the normal date output such as Day Feb 05 etc. This is because of future calculations.

Comment: When you call datepicker on thedate the second time, it's reinitializing datepicker again to default, WITHOUT your dateFormat.

Comment: What is the exact format you want

Comment: becaus mine does exactly what you're asking it to, dd-mm-yy, which is 23-10-2018. If you want different, state the exact format and we'll help

Answer (score 0):

You're reinitializing datepicker a second time, causing it to default

Try it this way:

```
/* FLOW DIFFERENTIATION */
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$( '#thedate' ).datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'M-dd'
    });

$('#checkDate').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedDate = $('#thedate').datepicker('getDate');

        console.log(selectedDate)
   });
```

If you're looking for Month - Day as specified in your post, it's `M-dd`

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initializing the "datepicker" in the bind function.
Just get the value that is set.
http://jsfiddle.net/nilanjan_mhatre/3rag2Lqd/

```
$(window).load(function(){
$( '#thedate' ).datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

$('#checkDate').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedDate = $('#thedate').val();

    console.log(selectedDate)
});
```